# Remove duplicates from ArrayList<String[]> - java

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I want to remove duplicate from an ArrayList.

If I do this, its working:

```
    List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add("a");
    test.add("a"); //Removing
    test.add("b");
    test.add("c");
    test.add("c"); //Removing
    test.add("d");

    test = test.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But if I want to remove duplicate String[] instead of String, its not removing duplicates:

```
    List<String[]> test = new ArrayList<>();

    test.add(new String[]{"a", "a"});
    test.add(new String[]{"a", "a"}); // Not removing
    test.add(new String[]{"b", "a"});
    test.add(new String[]{"b", "a"}); // Not removing
    test.add(new String[]{"c", "a"});
    test.add(new String[]{"c", "a"}); // Not removing

    test = test.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    ArrayList<String[]> test2 = (ArrayList<String[]>) test;
```

Any solution to fix this or another way to remove duplicate of an `ArrayList<String[]>`? Thanks

Comment: You'll have to work with `List<List<String>>` instead of `List<String[]>`, since arrays don't override Object's equals.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Eran notes, you can't work with arrays directly, since they don't override `Object.equals()`. Hence, arrays `a` and `b` are only equal if they are the same instance (`a == b`).

It's straightforward to convert the arrays to `List`s, which *do* override `Object.equals`:

```
List<String[]> distinct = test.stream()
    .map(Arrays::asList)                   // Convert them to lists
    .distinct()
    .map((e) -> e.toArray(new String[0]))  // Convert them back to arrays.
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/3sxaSq)